# gcc warning "implicit declaration of function ‘strnlen’" when dialect c99 or c11 used

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, c99, c11

*EDIT* Question is: how do I remove the warning */EDIT*
compiling (special cut-down test with just one #include)

```
#include <string.h>
void DeleteMe(){
    const char* pC = "ABC";
    int nLen = strnlen(pC, 255);
    char buffer[256];
    strncpy(buffer, pC, nLen);
}
```

With no dialect, it compiles no warning as

```
Building file: ../EzyThread.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"EzyThread.d" -MT"EzyThread.o" -o "EzyThread.o" "../EzyThread.c"
Finished building: ../EzyThread.c
```

making dialect c99 gives warning

```
Building file: ../EzyThread.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -std=c99 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"EzyThread.d" -MT"EzyThread.o" -o "EzyThread.o" "../EzyThread.c"
../EzyThread.c: In function ‘DeleteMe’:
../EzyThread.c:4:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strnlen’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int nLen = strnlen(pC, 255);
             ^
Finished building: ../EzyThread.c
```

making dialect c11 (my preferred option) gives warning

```
Building file: ../EzyThread.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"EzyThread.d" -MT"EzyThread.o" -o "EzyThread.o" "../EzyThread.c"
../EzyThread.c: In function ‘DeleteMe’:
../EzyThread.c:4:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strnlen’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int nLen = strnlen(pC, 255);
             ^
Finished building: ../EzyThread.c
```

**Extra info:**

- Oher parts of the project fail to compile under c90, so no info available
- Running under Ubuntu 16.04 which was an upgrade of 14.04
- Using

  Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

  Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
  Build id: 20170314-1500
- man strnlen

gives

```
STRNLEN(3)                 Linux Programmer's Manual                STRNLEN(3)

NAME
       strnlen - determine the length of a fixed-size string

SYNOPSIS
       #include <string.h>

       size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t maxlen);

   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       strnlen():
           Since glibc 2.10:
               _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700 || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
           Before glibc 2.10:
               _GNU_SOURCE
```

Comment: What is your question ? You asked the compiler for c99 or c11 compliance, and neither of those versions provide an `strnlen()` function in the string.h header.

Comment: Use gnu99, not c99. As an alternative, the man page tells you to define _XOPEN_SOURCE...

Comment: @nos searching elsewhere in stackoverflow led me to understand that strnlen was in string.h, as is strncpy

Comment: @Marc I do not see gnu99 as a dialect option. However adding -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L has indeed fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: If eclipse doesn't offer gnu99 as a dialect, and doesn't have a checkbox "enable gnu extensions", it probably has an option "other dialect" where you can write `-std=gnu99` yourself.

Comment: `strnlen` isn't standard C. Most likely because it is quite a useless function. Either a string is long enough and null terminated, or it is not. In case of the former, `strlen` works fine. In case of the latter, `strnlen` won't save the day anyway.

Comment: @Lundin `strnlen` is POSIX standard.It is useful for finding out the length of whatever is the result of your last `strncpy` call. Granted, one can argue that `strncpy` is quite a useless function, and they won't be too wrong.

Comment: @Lundin I want to create a stack-copy, up to 255/256 chars of an arbitrary string, so strnlen fits the bill perfectly. Just because you can't think of a use for a function, don't say it's quite useless. Perhaps consider programming languages as a smorgasbord - enjoy what you like, but don't spit on what you don't understand.

Comment: @brewmanz Or perhaps you simply don't know which tools are already available in standard C? Any reason why you can't use `memchr(str, '\0', n)` and `memcpy`? Too fast? Too standardized?

Comment: @Lundin You got me with that one. Clearly 10 years away from C is too long; I cannot see how to use memchr then memcpy without checking the pointer for null and using pointer arithmetic, both of which would obviously be neither fast nor standard. Please enlighten me.

Comment: @brewmanz `strnlen` returns max length if there is no null terminator, so you would have to check the result of the function no matter which one you use. Which of course is nothing in terms of performance, compared to the `n` number of comparisons you have to do. Full code: `char* end= memchr(str, '\0', n); if(ptr == NULL) {...} (void)memcpy(x, str, end-str+1);` Completely standard and certainly much faster than `strncpy`, which needlessly checks for a null terminator we _know_ isn't there until the end of the string. Feel free to benchmark.

Comment: @Lundin Full code indeed - you're hiding something! Yes, that {...} looks mighty suspicious, a bit non-standard, hiding a skeleton in the cupboard, and somewhat not benchmarkable. My code now looks like: 
int nBufLen = strnlen(szString, MAX_BUF_LEN - 1) + 1; 
buf[0] = '\0'; 
strncat(buf, szString, nBufLen - 1);
Just 3 lines, no branched logic, simpler arithmetic, easier to understand, by letting the functions handle the decisions. Maybe not the fastest code, but fast enough, and certainly easier to write, read and maintain than your ... incomplete mess.

Comment: Except your code will crash and burn in horrible ways if `szString` is not null terminated... You need to add `if(nBufLen == MAX_BUF_LEN - 1) {...}`. This is called error handling. The `...` is something called pseudo code. It has to be replaced with a way to handle the error. Which is supposedly the whole point of using strnlen over strlen in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin *sigh* I'm expecting a c-style string, and want to copy a maximum of 255 characters, and create a new c-style string. That I don't hit a null within the first 256 characters is fine; a properly terminated c-style string fitting in a buffer of 256 bytes will be the result.

Comment: @brewmanz Then you could use my code without the error checking. `char* end= memchr(str, '\0', n);  (void)memcpy(x, str, end-str+1);`. 2 lines. Very easy to understand. Completely standard. Fastest possible code.

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX systems like Linux and macOS, you need define the macro it specifies as the feature test macro, by passing `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` to the compiler or writing `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before the `#include`.

On Windows, you don’t need any special macros and can just use `strnlen` directly.

Note that the C standard doesn't actually define `strnlen`, but instead `strnlen_s`, which is similar but not quite identical. However, a lot of implementations don’t include it, and even for those which do you might need to define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to 1 before including `string.h`.

Comment: `strnlen_s` is only part of the C11 bounds-checking interface, an optional feature which doesn't seem to have much in the way of compiler support still(?).

Comment: @Lundin Huh, you’re right. Since Windows and POSIX, which make collectively make up the vast majority of implementations, both have `strnlen`, it seems more portable in practice even if it’s not standardized.

Comment: @Lundin I don’t suppose you know why the C standards committee went with `strnlen_s` when a lot of implementations already had `strnlen` and it doesn’t actually get you much extra safety (since you can check fur `NULL` yourself)?

Comment: I have no insight in that. The bounds-checking interface seems to be a fiasco so far. There's some sort of Microsoft lobby that's been preaching to use such functions and VC++ have similar functions. But then Microsoft has never shown the faintest interest in following the C standard, so I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use _GNU_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE
You can refer to this manual page https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strnlen.3.html

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

or

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOUCRE 200809L
```

Comment: It is supposed to be `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`